# SharePoint Designer 2013 - HTTP call not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am trying to make an HTTP call but I am not receiving a response back. I have `requestHeaders` in a variable with Authorization and Accept headers. I am able to successfully call this `webservice` through PostMan, but in SharePoint, it looks like it's stalling at the HTTP request. Any ideas?

**Just a note I am using Bearer authorization.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you are trying to call `/api` instead of `/_api`.

Comment: @DylanCristy Changed it and still not receiving a response...ran it in postman and it does not work with the underscore change.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood - I was assuming you were calling the SharePoint REST API, which does use the underscore.  If it's some other API then you need to use whatever their URL is, which seems to be with just `/api`, if it's working in Postman.

Comment: @DylanCristy yes, that's the strange thing...I am using the exact link in SharePoint Designer as I am in PostMan. It's strange I am not receiving any responseCode  back....it'd be helpful to get any sort of error...